# Should a link specify how it is to be opened?

Tags: html, hyperlink

For example HTML's href tag has a target attribute that can force the page to be opened in a new window. But conceptually is this a good idea? Should the content determine how the user should read it? Or should this be entirely up to the user (right click -> open in new window)?

Answer (score 0):

Normally when we redirect to a link which is of the current site then it should/may open in the same window. But if the link redirects us to another sire then its better to open it in a new window so that the user will stick to our(current) site. There is no specific rule. It is mainly done as per client's requirement.

One drawback of in opening the link using right--> click is it makes the user do one extra click. In case your page has 5 links and the user wants to open them in new windows/tabs each time he/she has to do an extra click. This is just an example. It all depends what the user wants.....

Answer (score 0):

I disagree. A link shouldn't be forced to open in a new window. If the user wants to open it in a new window then it is up to them.